# Enforcing Foreign Key Constraint Over Table From pg_dump With --exclude-table-data

Tags: postgresql, constraints, pg-dump, pg-restore

I'm currently working on dumping one of our customer's database in a way that allows us to create new databases from this customer's basic structure, but without bringing along their private data.

So far, I've had success with `pg_dump` combined with the `--exclude_table` and `exclude-table-data` commands, which allowed me to bring only the data I'll effectively need for this task.

However, there are a few tables that mix lines which references some of the data I left behind with other lines that references data that I had to bring, and this is causing me a few issues during the restore operation. Specifically, when the dump tries to enforce `FOREIGN KEY` constraints for certain columns on these tables, it fails because there are some lines with keys that have no matching data on the respective foreign table - because I chose to not bring this table's data!

I know I can log into the database after the dump is complete, delete any rows that reference data that no longer exists and create the constraint myself, but I'd like to automate the process as much as possible. Is there a way to tell `pg_dump` or `pg_restore` (or any other program) to not bring rows from table A if they reference table B if and table B's data was excluded from the backup? Or to tell Postgres that I'd like to have that specific foreign key to be active before importing the table's data?

For reference, I'm working with PostgreSQL 9.2 on a HREL 7 server.

Answer (score 0):

What if you disable foreign key checking when you restore your database dump? And after that remove lonely rows from the referring table.

By the way, I recommend you to fix you database schema so there is no chance wrong tuples being inserted into your database.